# Div inside grid not taking the alloted area

Tags: html, css

I have a container where I am using grid layout as show below

My HTML looks like this

```
<div class='pagelayout'>
<div class="tophalf">This div needs to occupy entire width of the page</div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like this

```
.pagelayout {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-template-columns: 70fr 30fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto  auto;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
  'tophalf tophalf'
  'leftside rightside'
}

.tophalf{
grid-area: tophalf;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.pagelayout {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-template-columns: 70fr 30fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'tophalf tophalf' 'leftside rightside'
}

.tophalf {
  grid-area: tophalf;
}
```

```html
<div class='pagelayout'>
  <div class="tophalf">This div needs to occupy entire width of the page</div>
</div>
```

But the div(This div needs to occupy entire width of the page) is only taking 70fr and the rest 30fr is left unused.

If I change the grid template like this, everythign is working fine.

```
.pagelayout {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
  'tophalf tophalf'
  'leftside rightside'
}

.tophalf{
grid-area: tophalf;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.pagelayout {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'tophalf tophalf' 'leftside rightside'
}

.tophalf {
  grid-area: tophalf;
}
```

```html
<div class ='pagelayout'>
  <div class ="tophalf">This div needs to occupy entire width of the page</div>
</div>
```

What is that I'm doing wrong in the first case?

Comment: Are you using react? Change className to class and it seems to work.

Comment: I'm using react. But the problem is there

Comment: The snippet seems to work. There is a small margin around the div but that can be removed by setting the body element to margin:0;

Answer (score 0):

`grid-template-columns: 70fr 30fr;`  this means create two colums one which takes 70fr & other which                                          takes 30fr

```css
grid-template-columns: 70fr 30fr;
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
```

```css
.pagelayout {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-template-columns: 70fr 30fr;  /*this means create two colums one which takes 70fr & other which takes 30fr*/
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  outline:2px solid green;
}

.tophalf {
  outline:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='pagelayout'>
  <div class="tophalf">This div needs to occupy entire width of the page</div>
</div>
```